# open command prompt through Visual studio ( C# ) , run some commands and then display the resultant details in the command prompt through a text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, cmd

This is the program I wrote to open cmd, run IPERF as a **client**.
After connecting with the server, it is supposed to show the bandwidth of the network.
But the command prompt closes and the information I require is only available at the server side.

How do I get the information and display it in a MessageBox ?

Any form of assistance is most appreciated.

```
string output;
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.ErrorDialog = false;
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
start.RedirectStandardError = true;
start.RedirectStandardInput = true;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo = start;
cmd.Start();
try
{
  Process.Start("cmd", "/C iperf -c " + IP_Address);
}
catch
{
}
Thread.Sleep(1000);
StreamReader outputReader = cmd.StandardOutput;
StreamReader errorReader = cmd.StandardError;         
output = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show( output );
```

Comment: Why do you have to run 'cmd', have you tried running the process directly?

Comment: You mention "server side".... why would you use `MessageBox` if this is client/server? That is quite possibly the problem here... what type of application is running this code?

Comment: Also: `Sleep(1000)` is avoidable; you can use `cmd.WaitForExit(1000)`, for example

Comment: I cannot run the process directly.It can only be executed through cmd prompt.Also i am supposed to display the information i obtain in cmd prompt, in the UI. I am using visual studio 2008 to run this code .

Answer (score 0):

`try
{
  Process.Start("cmd", "/C iperf -c " + IP_Address);
}`

Have you tried "cmd /k"? It should prevent the terminal from closing after completion of your argument.

`try
{
  Process.Start("cmd /k", "/C iperf -c " + IP_Address);
}`